# Persisting JSON while adding dynamic key and dynamic value by checking the old json value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, set

I have a json data like this , containing duplicate year value. I have to group the data by year with country:value (unique by year , means with same year there will be no duplicate country i.e in year 2003, it will not never occur that country europe is occured again ).

Below is a sample data which will be dynamically generated.

```
 {
      "data": [ {
                    "year": 2003,
                    "europe": 2.5
                },{
                    "year": 2003,
                    "namerica": 2.5
                },{
                    "year": 2003,
                    "asia": 2.1
                },{
                    "year": 2003,
                    "lamerica": 0.3
                },{
                    "year": 2003,
                    "meast": 0.2
                },{
                    "year": 2003,
                    "africa": 0.1
                }, {
                    "year": 2004,
                    "europe": 2.6
                },{
                    "year": 2004,
                    "namerica": 2.7
                },{
                    "year": 2004,
                    "asia": 2.2
                },{
                    "year": 2004,
                    "lamerica": 0.3
                },{
                    "year": 2004,
                    "meast": 0.3
                },{
                    "year": 2004,
                    "africa": 0.1
                }, {
                    "year": 2005,
                    "europe": 2.8
                  },{
                    "year": 2005,
                    "namerica": 2.9
                  },{
                    "year": 2005,
                    "asia": 2.4
                  },{
                    "year": 2005,
                    "lamerica": 0.3
                  },{
                    "year": 2005,
                    "meast": 0.3
                  },{
                    "year": 2005,
                    "africa": 0.1
        }]
    }
```

Below is the required output:

```
{
            "year": 2003,
            "europe": 2.5,
            "namerica": 2.5,
            "asia": 2.1,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.2,
            "africa": 0.1
        }, {
            "year": 2004,
            "europe": 2.6,
            "namerica": 2.7,
            "asia": 2.2,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.3,
            "africa": 0.1
        }, {
            "year": 2005,
            "europe": 2.8,
            "namerica": 2.9,
            "asia": 2.4,
            "lamerica": 0.3,
            "meast": 0.3,
            "africa": 0.1
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ar = {
    "data": [{
        "year": 2003,
        "europe": 2.5
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
        "namerica": 2.5
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
        "asia": 2.1
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
        "lamerica": 0.3
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
        "meast": 0.2
    }, {
        "year": 2003,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "europe": 2.6
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "namerica": 2.7
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "asia": 2.2
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "lamerica": 0.3
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "meast": 0.3
    }, {
        "year": 2004,
        "africa": 0.1
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "europe": 2.8
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "namerica": 2.9
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "asia": 2.4
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "lamerica": 0.3
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "meast": 0.3
    }, {
        "year": 2005,
        "africa": 0.1
    }]
};

// Extracting Distinct Years
var years = [];
for (var i = 0; i < ar.data.length; i++) {
    if (years.indexOf(ar.data[i].year) == -1) {
        years.push(ar.data[i].year);
    }
}

var requiredData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    var year = years[i];
    var objYear = {};
    objYear["year"] = year;
    for (var j = 0; j < ar.data.length; j++) {
        var obj = ar.data[j];
        if (obj.year == year){
            var secondKeyName = Object.keys(obj)[1];
            objYear[secondKeyName] = obj[secondKeyName];
        }
    }
    requiredData.push(objYear);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic data is very problematic, because the countries are seemingly random.

It would make it much easier to program up against this

```
{ "year": 2003, "country": "europe", "index": 2.3}
```

But i don't know if you have the possibility to do so.

---

What you have to do is this

```
let output = {};

for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    const dataIndex = data[i];
    const yearData = dataIndex.year;
    if(output[yearData] === undefined){
       output[yearData] = {"year":yearData};
    }
    const keys = Object.keys(dataIndex);
    for(let j=0;j<keys.length;j++){
       const key = keys[j];
       if(key !== "year"){
          const countryIndex = dataIndex[key];
          output[yearData][key] = countryIndex;
       }
    }
}
```

Now you go through each object and find the year, if year doesn't exist in the output, then we add it.

After this we have to go through all the keys of the object to find the country, we find the country by asking if the key isn't year, because we already added that.

The output you could look like this

```
const output = 
        { 
            "2003": {
                "year": 2003,
                "europe": 2.5,
                "namerica": 2.5,
                "asia": 2.1,
                "lamerica": 0.3,
                "meast": 0.2,
                "africa": 0.1
            }, 
            "2004":{
                "year": 2004,
                "europe": 2.6,
                "namerica": 2.7,
                "asia": 2.2,
                "lamerica": 0.3,
                "meast": 0.3,
                "africa": 0.1
            }
        };
```

So now you could say

```
console.log(output["2003"]["africa"]); // 0.1
```